# how can i solve nullptr problem in doubly linkedlist in c++?

Tags: c++, nullptr

i can't handle the nullptr problem.
when i execute begin().

```
nodelist::nodelist()
{
    Node* trailer = new Node();
    Node* header = new Node();
    header->next = trailer;
    trailer->prev = header;
    trailer->next = header->prev = NULL;
    n = 0;
}
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* prev;
    Node* next;
};
class nodelist
{
    public:
    void begin();
    private:
    Node* header;
    Node* tailer;
    Node* pos;
    int n;
}
void nodelist::begin()
{
    pos = header->next;
};
```

how can i make header and tailer pointer not to be a nullptr?
when i call nodelist L.begin() in main fuction, it alway creates this->header is nullptr exception.

Comment: You never set `nodelist::header` to a value in your constructor

Comment: `Node* header = ...` and `Node* trailer = ...` in your constructor are declaring two *local* variables that have nothing to do with the member variable of the same name (which are now shadowed).

Comment: But you got `n = 0;` right... Did you assume that there is some difference between `int` members and pointer members?